# How do I use the NetBarcode library to display an Barcode?

Tags: c#, wpf, barcode, code128

It's the first time I've used library. Hence the question I asked about the library:
[link](https://github.com/Tagliatti/NetBarcode)

Add a barcode to my label?
On the Website it says for a label it goes with it:

```
var barcode = new Barcode ("543534", Type.Code128, true);
```

But when I try to assign the value to the label, it doesn't work. So how do I have to use this library to add the barcode to a label?

Because I can't do much here:

[image: Picture]

if I want to get a barcode on a label?

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by assigning to the label? Do you mean a WinForms label? Or a physical label?

Comment: The "Show label" refers to the barcode image itself. If true, the code will be rendered as text below the barcode - if you want to show the barcode in your desktop app use the image for presentation

Comment: yes in an WPF project i want that, how do I need to write it when I got now an Image in my Program and gave it a name, how do I need to write the got that the Image got the Barcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way is to define a ValueConverter

```cs
public class StringToBarcodeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object? Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is string s)
        {
            var bc = new NetBarcode.Barcode(s, true);
            return bc.GetByteArray();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and use that inside the XAML.

```xml
<Image Source="{Binding Barcode, 
  Converter={StaticResource StringToBarcodeConverter}, 
  Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Comment: I tried this But it is not working :/

Comment: no i never used it, i just placed the Value Converter in my View Model

Comment: that would be so nice thank you

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/SirRufo/Barcoder - I also added a second kind of converter => https://github.com/SirRufo/Barcoder/tree/master/Barcoder.WpfApp/Converters

Comment: BTW It is a .net-6.0 VS2022 project

Comment: Ah so does it work, thank you for your help that will definitly help me to better understand thing like that.

Comment: did you got some on NET Framework 4.8 ? Because when I try to change that project to 4.8 ( which I need) he dosent find the ViewModel or the Converter, do you know how to fix that?

Comment: check the github repo again